# Converting keras functional model to keras class in tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am trying to convert a Keras functional model into class derived from tensorflow.keras.models.Model and I'm facing 2 issues. 
  1. I need to multiply 2 layers using tensorflow.keras.layers.multiply, but it returns a `ValueError: A merge layer should be called on a list of inputs`.
  2. If I remove this layern thus working with a classical CNN, it returns a `tensorflow.python.eager.core._SymbolicException:Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors, but found [<tf.Tensor 'patch:0' shape=(None, 64, 64, 3) dtype=float32>]`.

I would appreciate some guidance to convert my code. I'm using Python 3.7, TensorFlow 2.0rc2 and Keras 2.3.0. The class I have defined is the following:

```
class TestCNN(Model):
    """
      conv1 > conv2 > fc1 > fc2 > alpha * fc2 > Sigmoid > output
    """

    def __init__(self, input_dimension, n_category,**kwargs):
        """
        Instanciator
        :param input_dimension: tuple of int, theoretically (patch_size x patch_size x channels)
        :param n_category: int, the number of categories to classify,
        :param weight_decay: float, weight decay parameter for all the kernel regularizers
        :return: the Keras model
        """

        super(TestCNN, self).__init__(name='testcnn', **kwargs)

        self.input_dimension = input_dimension
        self.n_category = n_category

        self.conv1 = Conv2D(36, activation='relu', name='conv1/relu')
        self.conv1_maxpooling = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='conv1/maxpooling')
        self.conv2 = Conv2D(48, activation='relu', name='conv2/relu')
        self.conv2_maxpooling = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), name='conv2/maxpooling')
        self.flatten1 = Flatten(name='flatten1')

        self.fc1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc1/relu')
        self.fc2 = Dense(512, activation='relu', name='fc2/relu')
        self.alpha = TestLayer(layer_dim=128, name='alpha')
        self.output1 = TestSigmoid(output_dimension=n_category, name='output_layer')

    @tensorflow.function
    def call(self, x):

        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv1_maxpooling(x)

        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv2_maxpooling(x)
        x = self.flatten1(x)

        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)

        alpha_times_fc2 = multiply([alpha_output, fc2_output], name='alpha_times_fc2')

        return self.output1(alpha_times_fc2)


    def build(self, **kwargs):

        inputs = Input(shape=self.input_dimension, dtype='float32', name='patch')
        outputs = self.call(inputs)
        super(TestCNN, self).__init__(name="TestCNN", inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, **kwargs)
```

Then, in my main loop, I'm creating the instance as following:

```
testcnn = TestCNN(input_dimension=input_dimension, n_category=training_set.category_count)

optimizer = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(
            lr=parameter['training']['adam']['learning_rate'],
            beta_1=parameter['training']['adam']['beta1'],
            beta_2=parameter['training']['adam']['beta2'])

metrics_list = [tensorflow.keras.metrics.TruePositives]

loss_function = tensorflow.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
loss_metrics = tensorflow.keras.metrics.Mean()

testcnn.build()
testcnn.summary()
```

This code is raising the `tensorflow.python.eager.core._SymbolicException`. If I comment out some lines and return directly the results of the `fc2` layer, I've got the `ValueError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have commenter the `build()` function in my model and call it in my main script as following:

```
testcnn.build(input_dimension)
testcnn.compile(optimizer=adam_optimizer, loss=loss_function, metrics=metrics_list)
testcnn.summary()
```

Input dimension is a list formatted as following:

```
input_dimension = (batch_size, image_size, image_size, channels)
```